# Как определить недружелюбие/враждебность комментария?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, правки

Имеется [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1218816/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83-billin-play-market) который я имел неосторожность отредактировать))) Под данным вопросом развернулась дискуссия:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где меня попросили более адекватно проверять вопросы и редактировать с умом)) К слову сама правка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не знаю правильно ли я сделал что отметил тревогой данные комментарии, но с моей стороны мне кажется что "наезд" немного странный)) Я решил не начинать дискутировать на всякое-разное дабы меня не "успокоили" в качестве меры по разрешению конфликта, но положа руку на сердце как-то не очень приятно) Я не знаю может ли данный участник редактировать вопросы, но по-моему с его репой можно редакцию бросить в очередь где с ней ознакомятся. Я. сначала подумал может человек что-то перепутал и не так понял мою правку, но судя по всему нет :( Может не прав я, а не он ...

Comment: Скорее больше не оскорбление, а как мне кажется, просто недопонимание. Плюс немного дерзости. Судя по репутации участника, он еще не совсем здесь освоился.

Comment: @Sevastopol', да немного некорректно сформулировал вопрос здесь)) я тоже посмотрел на репу и на срок пребывания здесь думал может и правда впервые здесь, но 2 года как мне кажется достаточный срок) либо я чего-то не понимаю в этой жизни :)

Comment: Андрей, а вы поменьше обращайте внимание на поведение некоторых участников. Берегите свои нервы и здоровье, это важнее. Удачи!

Comment: @Sevastopol', спасибо за вашу поддержку)) Вам тоже удачного дня :D

Comment: Да ладно? Кого-то обидели в интернете? :) Как я вижу: не хочешь "конфликта", не продолжай дискуссию. А то, что кто-то кого-то назвал редиской (образно говоря), вообще не должно быть предметом внимания. А если тебе какую-то предъяву выражают, то есть 2 варианта: принять и исправить что-то, либо посчитать, что всё правильно сделал и игнорировать. Какие-то все нежные стали... Все люди разные, имеют часто противоположное мнение и отношение к тому или иному. Если думать о том, что можешь кого-то чем-то задеть, лучше вообще из дома не выходить и в интернет не заходить.

Comment: к андроид студии код точно не имеет отношение, это тоже самое что суп не вкусный в зеленой тарелке))

Answer (score 14):

Оскорблений в этих комментариях я не вижу, но они явно недружелюбные и враждебные. В [нормах поведениях](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/conduct#unfriendly-language) даются примеры куда более мягких комментариев, которые считаются недопустимыми в сообществе:

> **Никаких резких замечаний или враждебно настроенных фраз.**
> Какими бы ни были ваши намерения, подобное поведение может негативно отразиться на ваших коллегах.
> *«Если вы не утрудили себя прочитать мой вопрос, это не значит, что он дубликат».
>
> «Я задал вопрос не для того, чтобы его редактировали».*

Думаю, что тревога с причиной «Комментарий недружелюбен или враждебен» здесь вполне уместна.

В данном случае у человека не самое точное представление о работе сайта и, при желании, можно было попытаться подробнее объяснить ему в чем он не прав. Но не факт что это сработало бы, т.ч. вполне логично оставить эту задачу модератору.

Комментарии уже удалили, т.е. модератор с тревогой согласен. Модератор не оставил своих комментариев поэтому неясно получил ли участник обратную связь. Можно по крайней мере надеяться что он зайдет на мету.

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ, ваше мнение поможет сформировать картину отношения к такого родами ситуациям у сообщества) с оскорблением я видать все-таки погорячился))

Comment: Правила — это хорошо. Но ИМХО стоит сначала поговорить с тем, кто (вы думаете) их нарушил. Он может не знать/извиниться/удалить их сам/проч.

Comment: да, порой поговорить можно не спорю, но я после своего третьего комментария решил не вступать в полемику дабы не породить дискуссию, которая кстати никак не помогла ТС :(

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Согласен, но тут перед тем как ставить тревоги человеку два раза дали ответ на довольно резкие комментарии. Может с третьего раза Andrew до него достучался бы, а может это привело бы к взаимным оскорблениям. В любом случае тревоги по делу, а там уже как модератор разберется.

Comment: Модератор то разберется. ;D

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, точно! У модератора имеется в арсенале новое специальное успокоительное средство с формулировкой, которая звучит как музыка: `Для успокоения участников дискуссии`

Comment: @Sevastopol' Успокоительное номер один в России: успокаивает на ура.  ;D

Answer (score 8):

Мне очень нравится ответ default locale (оскорблений нет, тревога уместна, модераторы уже удалили и т.п.), дополню из своего опыта немного.

Для меня одним из чётких критериев недружелюбной фразы является  т.н. "пристройка сверху" (см. [википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F))), когда участник высокомерен, снисходителен, учительствует на тему как надо себя вести и что вам делать, обычно покровительственно-безапелляционным тоном.

Зачастую сложность вызывает то, что в интернете не видно невербалику, не слышно интонации и каждый участник домысливает эти вещи в соответствии со своим жизненным опытом.

В приведённом примере трижды встречается типовой маркер "то хотя бы (удосужьтесь)", который характерен для высокомерно-снисходительных фраз.

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ, комменты уже все снесли, так что они только тут остались)

Answer (score 5):

Для меня есть 2 индикатора враждебности/недружелюбности комментария:

1. Персонализированное тыканье, нравоучение
2. Жалоба/тревога другого юзера.

Меня самого то трудно задеть, кожа видимо толстая, уже и я, не выставляю тревоги, и игнорирую такие комментарии адресованные мне.

Раз уже речь зашла о банах, то баны от модератора за такие комментарии можно получить за массовые (> 5-6 тревог с недружелюбными комментариями за несколько дней). Не знаю как там настроен робот, который вычленяет такие кейсы, но время от времени появляется робот, который выделяет таких юзеров и выставляет тревогу для модератора.

Безусловно я проверяю кейсы присланные роботом и принимаю решение исходя из тяжести содеянного:

- игнор мнения робота (~10%)
- предупреждение юзеру (~70%)
- бан на несколько дней (~20%)

Безусловно бывают особо тяжкие кейсы, когда приходится банить юзера немедленно, не дожидаясь действий робота - за все время помню 1 такой случай, когда персонаж совсем уже разбушевался и начал применять весь арсенал великого, могучего с заходом в специфические арго.

Comment: спасибо большое за ваш ответ как представителя администрации :)

Comment: @Andrew модераторы - не представители администрации, они представители сообщества :)

Comment: Совершенно верно, представитель администрации у нас один @NicolasChabanovsky